# SQL Server: COUNT used with WHERE

Tags: sql-server, count, aggregate, where-clause, having

so I'd consider myself really new to SQL Server so the less used keywords like `HAVING` and `COUNT()` etc. So when I got this error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a
>   subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column
>   being aggregated is an outer reference.

I was really confused by the last bit. "a select list?" "column being aggregated is an outer reference?" Can anyone explain this in layman's terms?

Comment: Can you post your query? A select list is just a subquery usually used with IN, i.e. WHERE STATE in (select state from sometable)

Comment: I just made up a query using `COUNT` with `WHERE` to view the error message and better understand `COUNT` and it's limitations. There was no specific issue I was trying to solve. I just didn't understand the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SELECT-list is

```
SELECT a, b, c ...    <=== this list of expressions after SELECT
```

An outer reference is a column of the surrounding query referenced in a subquery. This is clearly explained here: [Aggregates with an Outer Reference](http://www.itprotoday.com/aggregates-outer-reference)

Note that the WHERE-clause is applied **before** grouping (with GROUP BY) and the HAVING-clause **after** grouping. Therefore the aggregate functions can appear in the HAVING-clause but not in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) as number_of_orders, SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM cust_orders
WHERE year(order_date) = 2017      -- filters records before grouping.
GROUP BY customer_id               -- groups while counting and summing up.
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2                -- count is available here.
```

This selects all the customer orders of the year 2017 and calculates the totals per customer. Only customers having more than 2 orders in this year are returned.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically saying you need to use a subquery that references another table if you want to use aggregates in those places:

```
SELECT A,
       B,
       C
FROM Table T
WHERE A = (SELECT MAX(D) FROM Table T2 WHERE T2.A = T.A) 
          --Valid, MAX(D) is an outer reference to another table we call T2

SELECT A,
       B,
       C
FROM Table T
WHERE A = MAX(D) --Invalid
```

The `HAVING` version would be something like this:

```
SELECT A,
       B,
       C
FROM Table T
GROUP BY A,
         B,
         C
HAVING COUNT(*) > (SELECT MAX(D) FROM Table T2) --Valid

SELECT A,
       B,
       C
FROM Table T
GROUP BY A,
         B,
         C
HAVING COUNT(*) > MAX(D) --Invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what it says is that you cannot do this:

```
WHERE COUNT(ColumnA) = 100
```

You need a `HAVING` after the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(ColumnA) AS CountA, ColumnB, ColumnC
FROM Table
GROUP BY ColumnB, ColumnC
HAVING COUNT(ColumnA) = 100
```